# Rails: How to use a belongs_to association for referencing in addition to a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many, belongs-to

Following set-up: A user can have many addresses, but at least one of them is the main address. A foreign key in the user table should be used as a pointer to the main address record.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  belongs_to :main_address, :class_name => 'Address', :foreign_key => 'main_address_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_address
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # used for has_many
end
```

This Set-Up works for just reading the main_address. But building is a problem, for example by using it in a complex form with nested attributes (Address fields) for creating.

I get the following error:
    `SQLite3::ConstraintException: addresses.user_id may not be NULL:`

The problem is, that the address is build via `main_address.build` and the address does not receive the foreign key `user_id` because it is build via `main_address`.

I have no idea :(
How can I use a belongs_to association for referencing a has_many association correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with lukewendling, the alternative is to establish an association in `Address` (to `User`) and then use a `before_save` to update the `user_id` if needed.  Something like this:

```
has_one :main_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'main_address_id'

before_save :update_user_id

def update_user_id
  if main_user.present?
    self.user_id = main_user.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modeling of the 'real' world seems a bit odd, and similarly, the association you're trying to make is complicated.  A User doesn't seem to belong to an MainAddress any more than a User belongs to her PrimaryVehicle.  Why not have a boolean on the Address model such as Address#primary? ?

Comment: Sure, this would be a solution, but I saw this approach in another software project and think it is smarter than just use a boolean attribute. So I hope anybody else has an idea...